# What is logging levels?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I know transports are the places where I want to keep my logs but I don't understand what is the level of logging? I have the following code to create a logger with multiple means of transport.

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/info.log', level: 'info' }),
  ],
})
```

When I want to log, `logger.log('error', err)`, it logs in both `info.log` and `error.log` files. Why is this happening? Can somebody explain the idea of levels in logging, please?

Comment: I didn't use Node.js, but I think this is something like Android's logcat, which any level will include those levels **more severe** than it, for example filtering `INFO` level will still have `ERROR` included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geno's comment is correct; in pretty much all logging platforms (winston, log4js, etc.), the *log level* represents the *maximum level* of error to print.

Setting log level to ERROR means "only print FATAL and ERROR messages".

Setting log level to INFO means "print FATAL, ERROR, WARN, and INFO messages".

There is no way (in Winston, at least, but I think it's generally true across the board) to specify a log transport that *only* carries INFO messages and *not* ERROR messages. This is by design.

When you set a log level, you are actually specifying a *level of detail* - FATAL is the least detailed logging, DEBUG is the most detailed logging. It wouldn't make sense to ask for more detail, and then have fatal errors disappear from the log. That is why every error level also includes all messages from levels "below" it.